# csv.DictWriter -- TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, csv, arguments

I'm trying to write a list of dictionaries to a CSV and am having issues initializing `csv.DictWriter()`. I've got:

```
fname = "Machine Detection Rate.csv"
with open(fname, "wb") as f:
    fieldNames = ["Number of Packets", "Number of Machines"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldNames=fieldNames, restval="", dialect="excel",)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in machineCounter:
        print "Got Here!"
        writer.writerow(line)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I've tried various permutations of arguments, but don't seem to be able to get it to run. I also don't seem to be able to find anyone else who's had the problem. The only arguments I haven't tried specifying are `*args` and `**kwds`. I'm a noob still and despite reading, I don't understand how they work in this situation. Any ideas?

Edit: in the final `for` loop I had `writer.writerows()` which did not output the all the dicts in the list. Changed to `writer.writerow()`.

Comment: i am not getting any error. May be there is error in the rest of the code from your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the parameter is `fieldnames` (all lowercase), not `fieldNames`:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldNames, restval="", dialect="excel",)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>>
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
...     fieldnames = ["Number of Packets", "Number of Machines"]
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldNames=fieldnames, restval="", dialect="excel",)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)
>>>
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
...     fieldNames = ["Number of Packets", "Number of Machines"]
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldNames, restval="", dialect="excel",)
...
>>> writer
<csv.DictWriter instance at 0x01AD8E90>
>>>
```

Note that Python doesn't complain with an error such as:

`TypeError: DictWriter got an unexpected keyword argument 'fieldNames'`

because `csv.DictWriter` happens to have a `**kwds` parameter.  You can see it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) if you look at the signature:

`class csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)`

This parameter will accept any number of keyword arguments.